# how to create Custom UIMenuController with only custom items other than default?

Tags: swift, menuitem, uimenucontroller

I have requirement to show menu items on uiwebview whenever user selects any text. 
[image]

I have tried

```
let highlightMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Highlight", action: #selector(ViewController.hightlight))

UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuItems = [highlightMenuItem]
```

but this only appends more menu item with default existing one. as this

[image]
[image]

Is there any way out to achieve this with only menu items Copy, Highlight and Note?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve this by subclassing `UIWebView` and overriding `canPerformAction` (Swift 3). Then, all you need to do is return `false` for whichever actions you want disabled.

Example:

```
class EditedUIMenuWebView: UIWebView {

  override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(cut(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(select(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    ...

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
  }

}
```

If you have any questions please ask!

**Edit** If you want to disable all actions but a few it may be easier to just return `false` in `canPerformAction` and return `true` for the ones you want like so:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
   if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(customMethod(_:)) {
     return true
   }
   ...
   return false
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ike10, for editing, yes this is good approach to ignore other actions. and only to keep our custom one.

Comment: this doesnt work if you want to filter out the copy action. In order to filter the copy action, you need to display your own menucontroller

Comment: I've tried this in UITextView and it is not working. I can add menu items, but not get rid of the existing ones. Is there another solution or does UITextView work differently?