# How to Remove UIMenuController Default Items In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I'm trying to remove the items ***Look Up*** & ***Share...*** from the UIMenuController. How would I specifically remove the two and keep my custom one. Here is what I've achieved so far:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // add two custom menu items to the context menu of UIWebView (assuming in contenteditable mode)


        let menuItem1 = UIMenuItem(title: "My Button", action: #selector(myButtonSel))
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [menuItem1]

    }
```

Here is the canPerformAction I have:

```
  override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

        //let shareSelector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString("_share:")

        if webView?.superview != nil {
            if action == #selector(myButtonSel){
                return true
            }
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
```

Also for some odd reason, when I try to remove all the default items and keep only my custom, it does not work. Here is the code I attempted for that:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    //let shareSelector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString("_share:")

    if webView?.superview != nil {
        if action == #selector(myButtonSel){
            return true
        }
        else {

            return false
        }
    }

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Even when I try to remove all of the other items and keep my custom, I'm not able to do so. All I'm able to do is add my custom item.

Comment: Are you getting a SIGBART error? In that case, please check the "Connections Inspector" tab in the right hand menu? If you see some names you deleted from story board or code, but they are still there - you should delete theme from Connections Inspector.

Comment: @KuboAndTwoStrings No, I didn't get any errors, my custom menu works, but I just can't seem to remove the UIMenuController Items. The code is just ignored whenever I try to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this but it worked for my by subclassing the WebView and overriding `canPerformAction` method, inside which I manually removed the default options.

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(cut(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(select(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    ...

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
  }
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37946329/2570153) answer by **Ike10** and it had worked for me. Give it a shot.

Comment: Is there any other way without being rejected, because the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview At the bottom, it says UIWebView should not be subclassed.

Comment: Also, how would check the selected text. This isn't working: webViewHere.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.getSelection().toString();"

Comment: Ok, so after some research I discovered that it isn't against the policy to subclass a UIWebView. Also, I just used NSNotification to call a function from the ViewController.

Comment: Yea and I guess subclassing is way to go for other ui elements such as uitextview, uitextfield, etc. You learn something new everyday. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Objective C version of removing default items from UIMenuController. The default items are part of  [UIResponderStandardEditActions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions?language=objc)! For removing default items make sure to create a subclasss of UITextField or UITextView for the functionality to work otherwise in UiViewController class it will not work.

```
#import "CustomTextField.h"

@implementation CustomTextField



- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
if (action == @selector(captureTextFromCamera:) ||
    action == @selector(delete:) ||
    action == @selector(cut:) ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action)  isEqualToString:@"_promptForReplace:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_transliterateChinese:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_insertDrawing:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_lookup:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_define:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_translate:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_addShortcut:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_accessibilitySpeak:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:"] ||
    [NSStringFromSelector(action) isEqualToString:@"_share:"] )
{
    return  false;
}
NSLog(@"OPtion :- %@",NSStringFromSelector(action));

return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}


@end
```

The default available options are below which you want to disable.

```
cut:
copy:
paste:
delete:
_promptForReplace:
_transliterateChinese:
_insertDrawing:
captureTextFromCamera:
_showTextStyleOptions:
_lookup:
_define:
_translate:
_addShortcut:
_accessibilitySpeak:
_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
_share:
makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
```

For swift users please convert it . It is easy to convert.